Conjecture: The $n$th left Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 (x-x^2)^k dx$ is $B(k+1,k+1) + \Theta(n^{-2 \lceil (k+1)/2\rceil})$
While playing around on Wolfram Alpha with integrals of the form $\int_0^1 (x-x^2)^k dx$, where it happens that Wolfram Alpha displays formulas for the $n$th left Riemann sum (using equally spaced partitions), I noticed that a lot of terms appeared to be cancelling out and so we would get much faster convergence than expected:
$$k=1: S_n = \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{6n^2} = \frac{1}{6} + \Theta(n^{-2})\\
k=2: S_n = \frac{n^4-1}{30n^4} = \frac{1}{30} + \Theta(n^{-4})\\
k=3: S_n = \frac{3n^6+7n^2-10}{420n^6} = \frac{1}{140} + \Theta(n^{-4})\\
k=4: S_n = \frac{n^8+20n^2-21}{630n^8} = \frac{1}{630} + \Theta(n^{-6})\\
k=5: S_n = \frac{n^{10}-22n^4+231n^2-230}{2772n^{10}} = \frac{1}{2772} + \Theta(n^{-6})\\
k=6: S_n = \frac{5n^{12}-3003n^4+18200n^2-15202}{60060n^{12}} = \frac{1}{12012} + \Theta(n^{-8})\\
\vdots$$
(Whereas for example, the $n$th left Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 x^k dx$, for fixed positive integer $k$, is $\frac{1}{k+1} + \Theta(n^{-1})$.)
So I found myself curious whether this pattern would continue for higher fixed positive integers $k$, so that $S_n = B(k+1,k+1) + \Theta(n^{-2 \lceil (k+1)/2\rceil})$, and if so how that could be proved.

The constant term is just  $\frac{(2 n+1)!}{(n!)^2}$

Using the Euler–Maclaurin formula, we can express $S_n$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
S_n  = B(k + 1,k + 1) + \frac{{f(1) - f(0)}}{n} & + \sum\limits_{m = 1}^M{\frac{{B_m }}{{m!}}(f^{(m - 1)} (1) - f^{(m - 1)} (0))\frac{1}{{n^m }}} 
\\ & - \frac{1}{{n^M }}\frac{1}{{M!}}\int_0^1 {\widetilde B_M ( - nt)f^{(M)} (t)\,{\rm d}t} .
\end{align*}
Here, $\widetilde B_{M}(x)$ denotes the $M^{\text{th}}$ periodic Bernoulli polynomial, and $f(x)=(x-x^2)^k$. From
$$
f^{(j)} (x) = \sum\limits_{r = 0}^j {( - 1)^{j - r} \binom{j}{r}\frac{{k!}}{{(k - r)!}}\frac{{k!}}{{(k - j + r)!}}x^{k - r} (1 - x)^{k + r - j} } ,
$$
we observe that $f^{(m-1)} (1) - f^{(m-1)} (0)$ becomes non-zero for the first time when $m=2 \lceil (k+1)/2\rceil$.
